# Spring : Error creating bean , broken pipeline after deployment

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat, jdbc, mybatis

I'm having this recurrent error when I deploy my aplication on my university's application server.1 or 2 days after I deploy my aplication I get the error message bellow when I enter the application's url . Once this happens I have deteccted several things.

1. If I refresh the web page , the error disappears
2. Once this happens , an hour or so later my database model just completely freezes , and It doesnt allow other applications that use that model to operate , making those applications freeze too.
3. The only way to fix this is to restart the server.

Here is my aplicationContext file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="pe.edu.sistemas.sisdiho" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="pe.edu.sistemas.sisdiho.mappers" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="pe.edu.sistemas.sisdiho.entities" />
    <property name="mapperLocations"
        value="classpath*:pe/edu/sistemas/sisdiho/mappers/**/*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"></property>
</bean>
```

And here is the error found on my server logs

```
ago 22, 2014 10:10:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:     
El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Faces Servlet] en el contexto con ruta [/sisdiho] lanzó la excepción 
[Error creating bean with name 'commonLaboScheduleController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
The last packet successfully received from the server was 60.409.421 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 60.409.421 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.] con causa raíz java.net.SocketException: broken Pipeline
```

The most recent error log I have is 20 pages long so I'll link the error log shared on my drive.

[Application error log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dlFtiwpSn1d1hSzCymN8tZqmZe1hOkYlwiGgd7rz2y8/edit?usp=sharing)

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?How can I fix it?

Im using :
Spring Tool Suite
MyBatis
Mysql
Primefaces

Comment: As a first order of business, make sure all timeouts are in sync. Db connection pool, db itself and any other place a db connection might be kept alive for a while. If a dead connection gets returned from a pool, something like this might occur. As a second, configure connection checking in the pool as you might be getting corrupted ones.

Comment: Im sorry but how I can edit that , I'm really new to this whole thing of servers and databases . I'm using spring tool suite and mysql database with phpmyadmin.Where can I check or change these settings.

Comment: For MySQL, if you didn't touch anything the default will be very long (8h I think). I'm guessing you're using some kind of connection pooling, right? But what? The one provided by Tomcat? c3p0? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to another connection pool in and see if it works for you:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"></property>
</bean>
```

Some other java connection pool includes:

- tomcat connection pool, example here http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2013/01/30/Using-Tomcat-JDBC-connection-pool-in-a-standalone-environment
- c3p0, one example in here http://syntx.io/configuring-c3p0-connection-pooling-with-spring-and-hibernate/
- bonecp, example in http://jolbox.com/index.html?page=http://jolbox.com/configuration-spring.html
- druid connection pool, example in https://github.com/alibaba/druid/wiki/%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE_DruidDataSource%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE